# cache git clone requests through squid

Tags: cache, squid, git

Our build/ci server and developer workstations need to clone lots of repositories so we need to reduce time of downloading these repos.

Is there any way to cache git clone request through squid or whatever cache mechanism for both HTTP/HTTPS and git:// ?

Comment: Where are the git repositories located? Where do you plan to install the proxy server? Have you measured that it is the git server that is the bottleneck?

Comment: we use gitlab for private repos but most of other depending repos comes from github and gopkg.in. Each time a build triggered through the git push, build server begins to fetch required repo and libraries to build.
this fetching process takes too much time to complete. Furthermore, developers need download these repos every time they develop and test locally.

Because of some country limitation we haven't direct access to golang or gopkg repositories so we're using proxy to download these repositories that makes the process much worse.